# Retrieve data from data lake to analytical system

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, analytical

We have  created a new data lake in Hadoop file system. Data is stored in the form of ORC. Currently analytical system is directly connecting to data lake to read these ORC file.

Is there any way to create a middle layer between data lake and analytical system to serve data ?

Answer (score 0):

Which are your analytical software?
Is it possible to use the API or the RESTful web services to access the data lake?
Please, clarify a little more.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very generic, but one common and easy way to build a data lake is to use Presto (https://prestodb.io).

Presto can read several formats, but also connect to different data sources like mysql databases and others, presenting the data as table.

Clients can use SQL, also through jdbc/odbc and hence access the data lake even from tools like excel, or other analytical tools (microstrategy, tableau, etc).